# Laravel working out with multiple data in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I am working on a laravel base profiling system.

Example tables..

**Person**

```
id | Name   | sports_id
1  | foo    | 1,2
2  | bar    | 2,3
3  | derp   | 1,3
```

**Sports**

```
id | Name       |
1  | basketball |
2  | volleyball |
3  | swimming   |
```

Question:

**How can I get all `Name` records from `Person` table, which have `sports_id` corresponding to value `basketball` only from `Sports` table?**

Because I'm confused on how to execute the query such as above due to the `Person` table is not normalized.

Or

**Is there a way to normalize the `Person` table, so that I can query properly?**

Comment: it is many to many relationship see https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really use [many-to-many relationshsip](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships) here.

If for some reason you don't want to then use simple query:

```
User::where('sports_id', 2)->get();
```

Comment: `only` clause is not true with this solution.

Comment: @PseudoAj, what `only` clause?

Comment: "person's name, who's sports are basketball only?" I am thinking Jefsama is looking for `only basketball` meaning id `2` instead of `%,2,%`

Comment: @PseudoAj, oh yeah I've missed 'only basketball' part. Fixed the code. Thanks.

Comment: ohh thought it would get complicated. I will try to use `many-to-many-relationship` and i hope it works the way i want. thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You need create additional table for relationships called `persons_sports`. So your tables will looks like

```
persons [id, name]
sports [id, name]
persons_sports [person_id, sport_id]
```

Then you'll need add relationships to your models

```
// In Person class
public function sports()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Sport::class)
}
```

Then you can search persons like

```
$sport_name = 'basketball';

$persons = Person::whereHas('sports', function ($query) use ($sport_name) {
    $query->where('name', $sport_name);
})->get();
```